# Symfony2 + Doctrine Association Error: Class Game has no association named home

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Here are the columns and rows of the MySQL tables:
[image]

I'm trying to inner join the game.home and game.away with the Team.id, but i'm getting the error:  "Error: Class Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\Game has no association named home" what am I doing incorrectly?

Here is the desired results I want to achieve, I know how to do it in MySQL, but not Symfony and Doctrine:

```
select 
    t1.id as gameid, 
    t1.season as gameseason, 
    t1.gametype as gametype, 
        t2.id as homeid, 
        t2.name as homename, 
        t2.abbreviation as homeabbreviation, 
        t2.type as hometype, 
        t2.image as homeimage,
            t3.id as awayid, 
            t3.name as awayname, 
            t3.abbreviation as awayabbreviation, 
            t3.type as awaytype, 
            t3.image as awayimage from Game t1 
            INNER JOIN Team t2 on t1.home  = t2.id
            INNER JOIN Team t3 on t1.away  = t3.id;
```

Here are my Doctrine entities:

**Game.orm.yml:**

```
Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\Game:
    type: entity
     OneToOne:
        targetEntity: Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\Team
    JoinColumn:
        name: home
        referencedColumnName: id
    repositoryClass: Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\GameRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
        home:
            type: integer  
        away:
            type: integer
        season:
            type: string
        gametype:
        type: integer
        username:
        type: string
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Team.orm.yml**

```
Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\Team:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\TeamRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
            strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        abbreviation:
            type: string
            length: 255
        type:
            type: string
            length: 255
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        image:
            type: string
            length: 255
        username:
            type: string
            length: 255
    lifecycleCallbacks:
        prePersist: [ uploadImage ]
        prePersist: [ preUpload ]
        preUpdate: [ preUpload ]
        postPersist: [ moveImage ]
        preRemove: [ removeImage ]
```

**GameRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * GameRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class GameRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function allByUsername($username)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:Game')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t','g')
        ->innerJoin('t.home', 'g')
        ->setParameter('username', $username);
        $token = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $token;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html#example) your mapping should look like:

**Game.orm.yml:**

```
Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\Game:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\GameRepository
    oneToOne:
        home:
            targetEntity: Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\Team
            joinColumn:
                name: home
                referencedColumnName: id
        away:
            targetEntity: Travel\Bundle\TravelBundle\Entity\Team
            joinColumn:
                name: away
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: you can't have multiple `oneToOne` entries (I mean string 'oneToOne') as you have here http://pastebin.com/CpabpW4B I edited my answer so check one `oneToOne` entry with 2 relations: `home` and `away`